# How to replace square brackets and set dot before replacement?

Tags: javascript, string, replace

Good day.

I wish to replace square brackets inside string and set dot before replacement.

For example, Current string `position[0].type` i need transform to next one `position.0.type`

I have tried making it by this rule `'position[0].type'.replace(/[[\]]/g, '')`
as expected, will removed only brackets, how i can set needed dot?

Thanks.

Comment: The replacement, it must be `'.'`, not an empty string. And use `/[[\].]+/g`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Did u try before answer? Just open console log and try and u will get ```'position.0..type'```

Comment: Use `/[[\].]+/g` regex along with that replacement. `.replace(/[[\].]+/g, '.')`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yep, this is it, thanks. Give me pls it as answer, i will mark as right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
.replace(/[[\].]+/g, '.')
```

The `[[\].]+` regex matches one or more (`+`) `[`, `]` or `.` chars. `g` makes it match all occurrences and `'.'` replaces the matches with a single `.`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly property name should be string , then let you try to make it number , you cant call it directly like obj.0 or obj.2 , you can call like obj['1'] or obj.[1] and if u dont want to give up finally u can do

```
let aObj = {
    0:{
        type:'exampleType'
    }    
}
const { 0:numkey } = aObj; 

console.log(numkey.type)
```